# Query Classes(Q- classes not generated) for Querydsl mongodb

Tags: mongodb, querydsl

**Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QuerydslMongoPredicateExecutor]** and **hence the Q classes were not generated**. Can anyone help me with what could be the issue with that?

**I've added the required dependencies and the plugin as mentioned below:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.6</version>
</dependency>   



<plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                                <processor>
                                    org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor
                                </processor>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

**Below is the error that I'm facing:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.demo.QUser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:274) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.SimpleEntityPathResolver.createPath(SimpleEntityPathResolver.java:55) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: How and from where do you start application. Because by default IDEA and Eclipse used another compiled source folder.??

Comment: @borino I'm using Eclipse and have mentioned the folder for the Query class creation in the plugin for querydsl-apt